Was Sarah just very beautiful, or was something else going on?
Genesis tells us that Abraham nearly lost his wife on two occasions due to his lack of faith. Firstly to Pharaoh (Genesis 12), and then to Abimelech (Genesis 20).
But what is confusing me is that, even by their own reckoning, Abraham and Sarah were both very old. In fact, that's one of the main reasons that they are commended for their faith, because they were well past childbearing age. In fact, Hebrews 11 says Abraham was 'as good as dead'.
If you follow the scriptures where their ages are mentioned, Sarah appears to be around 65 when Pharaoh sees her, and around 90(!) when Abimelech sees her! How do these two narratives converge? On the one hand, Sarah is a very old lady, and on the other hand she seems to be very desirable 'wife' material wherever she goes.

Keep in mind she died at 127 years old so, relatively speaking, at 90 she might have looked somewhat like a 40 to 50-year-old woman who dies at 80 and not so much like we picture a 90 year old nowadays.

That's a fair point, but interesting to consider that the understanding of childbearing age was very similar to today

I don't know but there can some very attractive women even in their seventies today. Back then there was probably less genetic errors that have built built up in the human genome over the millennia so if you lived a good life and had good genetics one could look pretty good well into their elder years.

One shouldn't judge their physical health by modern standards: Abraham died at 175, while Sarah died at 127 - so they were still "middle-aged" at the time of going to Egypt... and by comparison to the life-span of earlier patriarchs they were simply "young". Also, the notion of "beauty" was quite different from ours - Sarah was likely covered in cloth from head to toes, her only noticeable feature being her rounded forms - and those likely corresponded not to Angelina Jolie physique, but simply being well fed.

The Torah makes Sarah's beauty known.

Genesis 12:11 - And it came to pass, when he was close to
entering Egypt, that he said to Sarai his wife, “Indeed I know that
you are a woman of beautiful countenance.

According to the Midrash, at twenty she still had the beauty of a seven-year-old, and at one hundred she was just as pure from sin as she had been at twenty.

And the life of Sarah was one hundred years and twenty years and seven
years: The reason that the word “years” was written after every digit
is to tell you that every digit is to be expounded upon individually:
when she was one hundred years old, she was like a twenty-year-old
regarding sin. Just as a twenty-year-old has not sinned, because she
is not liable to punishment, so too when she was one hundred years
old, she was without sin. And when she was twenty, she was like a
seven-year-old as regards to beauty. — from Gen. Rabbah 58:1] [1]

The rabbis questioned why Sarah isn't mentioned in Genesis 12:14, which says, "When Abram entered Egypt." According to the midrashic interpretation, Abraham shut up a chest to try and hide her from the Egyptians.

“It was upon Abram’s arrival in Egypt, the Egyptians saw” – and where
was Sarah? He had placed her in a chest and locked her in it. When
they arrived at customs, they said to him: ‘Pay the duty.’ He said: ‘I
will pay the duty.’ They said to him: ‘[Perhaps] you are transporting
garments?’ He said: ‘I will pay [the duty] for garments.’ They said to
him: ‘[Perhaps] you are transporting gold?’ He said: ‘I will pay [the
duty] for gold.’ They said to him:’ Perhaps you are transporting silk
garments?’ He said: ‘I will pay [the duty] for silk garments.’
‘[Perhaps] you are transporting gems?’ He said: ‘I will pay [the duty]
for gems.’ [Nevertheless,] they said to him: ‘It is not possible [for
you to pass] unless you open [the chest] and show us what is inside
it.’ When he opened it, the entire land of Egypt shone with her radiance.


She was beautiful: The Torah tells us about Sarah’s beauty in several passages. For instance, Genesis 12:11 and the fact that despite her age, Sarah’s beauty was so remarkable that it caught the attention of powerful men like Pharaoh and Abimelech.
Rabbi Ḥanina bar Pappa says that even Abishag the Shunammite was not half as beautiful as Sarah:

She still did not reach half the beauty of Sarah, as it is written:
“Ad me’od,” which can be translated as “up to very fair,” but not
including the praise of “very fair.” By contrast, it is written
concerning Sarah: “She was very fair” (Genesis 12:14).

The Rabbis also say:

Rabbi Bena’a says: I gazed at his, Adam’s, two heels, and they shone
so brightly that they are similar to two suns. Along these lines, the
Gemara states that all people compared to Sarah are like a monkey compared to a human, as Sarah was exceedingly beautiful; Sarah
compared to Eve is like a monkey compared to a human; Eve compared to
Adam is like a monkey compared to a human; and Adam compared to the
Divine Presence is like a monkey compared to a human.

Rabbi Huna and Rabbi Avun said in the name of Rabbi Meir:

It was so that their husbands could enjoy them, for whenever a woman
carries a fetus, she becomes unsightly and neglected. All ninety years that Sarah did not bear children, she was as [beautiful as] a bride under her wedding canopy.


Sarah had great character: Hebrews 11:11 points out her faith.

By faith Sarah herself also received strength to conceive seed, and
she bore a child when she was past the age, because she judged Him
faithful who had promised.

Furthermore, 1 Peter 3:6 talks about her obedience and respect towards Abraham, which reflects her character.
I believe that Sarah being desired by other men despite her age can also be seen as a testament to God’s favor and protection over her and Abraham.
Conclusion: Sarah was indeed very beautiful; her story is about more than just her physical attractiveness. It’s also about her character, her relationship with God, and the favor of God she enjoyed.

Very good conclusion! I was wondering where did you get the information about what Rabbis teach about Sarah’s beauty? Is there a site you’d recommend?

@MadelineC. I use Sefaria. Home to 3,000 years of Jewish texts. You can learn about how to use it here.

@MadelineC. I second Jason's suggestion. An easy gateway is to look up any OT bible verse at Sefaria and then check for various commentaries. This is a work in progress and many things are still in Hebrew but they have done a great service so far.
